# Importar tabela no R sem os nomes (pular linha não funcionou)

Tags: r, importação

estou tentando importar alguns dados para o R, mas não importa o que eu faça, vem sempre uma linha com os nomes das colunas (informações de uma linha que eu quero pular). 
Está é a tabela:

[image: Quero importar as informações a partir da linha 2]

No entanto, no R, mesmo pulando a primeira linha, essas informações vêm junto.

[image: Mesmo pulando a linha 1, as infoirmações em destaque são importadas]

Segue código para reproducibilidade do problema:

```
library(tidyverse)
dados <- tribble(
  ~Regiao, ~`Obitos fetais`, ~X1, ~X2, ~X3, ~X4, ~Obitos, ~X5, ~X6, ~X7, ~X8,
  NA, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009,  2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009,
  "Norte", 2106, 2159, 2038, 2119, 2099, 52815, 52286, 53538, 5507, 57375,
  "Nordeste", 6896, 6776, 6479, 6941, 6947, 242303, 248049, 258049, 263198, 267177,
  "sudeste", 12356, 11749, 11213, 10962, 10632, 478126, 493358, 493478, 501578, 511492,
  "Sul", 3605, 3462, 3251, 3221, 3024, 159760, 163914, 169124, 169337, 174871,
  "Centro-Oeste", 1856, 1922, 1781, 1725, 1710, 60573, 62585, 64353, 66641, 68301
)

library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(dados, "meusdados.xlsx", sheetName = "tipo4")

tipo4 <- xlsx::read.xlsx("meusdados.xlsx", "tipo4", starRow = 2, endRow = 7)
```

Comment: me parece um erro de digitação: o nome do argumento é `startRow` e vc usou `starRow`.

Comment: @Maniero Eu só trocaria o motivo de fechamento p/ "Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um **erro de digitação**. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável."

Comment: @DanielFalbel feito!

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

## Em uma frase

Conforme indicado nos comentários, trata-se de um erro de digitação e ele pode ser corrigido trocando o argumento `starRow` (sem o `t`) por `startRow`.

```
tipo4 <- xlsx::read.xlsx("meusdados.xlsx", "tipo4", starRow = 2, endRow = 7)
tipo4
        Regiao Obitos.fetais    X1    X2    X3    X4 Obitos     X5     X6     X7     X8 starRow
1         <NA>          2005  2006  2007  2008  2009   2005   2006   2007   2008   2009       2
2        Norte          2106  2159  2038  2119  2099  52815  52286  53538   5507  57375       2
3     Nordeste          6896  6776  6479  6941  6947 242303 248049 258049 263198 267177       2
4      sudeste         12356 11749 11213 10962 10632 478126 493358 493478 501578 511492       2
5          Sul          3605  3462  3251  3221  3024 159760 163914 169124 169337 174871       2
6 Centro-Oeste          1856  1922  1781  1725  1710  60573  62585  64353  66641  68301       2
```

e uma vez corrigido,

```
tipo4 <- xlsx::read.xlsx("meusdados.xlsx", "tipo4", startRow = 2, endRow = 7)
tipo4
           NA. X2005 X2006 X2007 X2008 X2009 X2005.1 X2006.1 X2007.1 X2008.1 X2009.1
1        Norte  2106  2159  2038  2119  2099   52815   52286   53538    5507   57375
2     Nordeste  6896  6776  6479  6941  6947  242303  248049  258049  263198  267177
3      sudeste 12356 11749 11213 10962 10632  478126  493358  493478  501578  511492
4          Sul  3605  3462  3251  3221  3024  159760  163914  169124  169337  174871
5 Centro-Oeste  1856  1922  1781  1725  1710   60573   62585   64353   66641   68301
```

## Aprendendo com o erro

O erro aconteceu de forma silenciosa e isso dificulta encontrá-lo e entendê-lo.

O [r](/questions/tagged/r) fez isso porque achou que o argumento `starRow = 2` era o comando para incluir uma coluna com esse nome (olhe a última coluna do primeiro caso e mesmo na screenshot da pergunta).

Então, quando algo sair diferente do esperado, olhar para o resultado com calma pode ajudar a entender a origem do problema e como resolvê-lo.

Além disso, o uso do `autocomplete` oferecidos por IDEs (como o `RStudio`), pode ajudar na prevenção de problemas como esse. [Aqui](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205273297-Code-Completion) tem informações sobre o autocomplete no `RStudio`.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado por encontrar o erro e por essa sua dica "Aprendendo com o Erro". Me ajudou muito! 
valeu!

Comment: O erro foi encontrado pelo @Daniel, só coloquei como resposta :P

Comment: Ops.
Obrigado mesmo assum! :)